# Declare properties to ignore in entities interface (EF Core)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

EF  Core 2.2

Having this interface:

```
public interface INotPersistingProperties
{
   string MyNotPersistingPropertyA { get; set; }
   string MyNotPersistingPropertyB  { get; set; }
}
```

and a lot of entities that implements the interface

```
public class MyEntity : INotPersistingProperties
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string MyNotPersistingPropertyA { get; set; }
  public string MyNotPersistingPropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

is there any chance to automatically ignore, for all entities that implement the  INotPersistingProperties, those properties (using Fluent API)?

Comment: You can use `NotMapped` with such properties

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently EF Core does not provide a way to define custom conventions, but you can add the following to your `OnModelCreating` override (after all  entity types are discovered) to iterate all entity types implementing the interface and call `Ignore` fluent API for each property:

```
var propertyNames = typeof(INotPersistingProperties).GetProperties()
    .Select(p => p.Name)
    .ToList();
var entityTypes = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .Where(t => typeof(INotPersistingProperties).IsAssignableFrom(t.ClrType));
foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
{
    var entityTypeBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType);
    foreach (var propertyName in propertyNames)
        entityTypeBuilder.Ignore(propertyName);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can put `NotMapped` on the properties in the interface and then use [MetadataType attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_MetadataTypeAttribute__ctor_System_Type_)

```
public interface INotPersistingProperties
{
   [NotMapped]
   string MyNotPersistingPropertyA { get; set; }
   [NotMapped]
   string MyNotPersistingPropertyB  { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(INotPersistingProperties))]
public class MyEntity : INotPersistingProperties
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string MyNotPersistingPropertyA { get; set; }
  public string MyNotPersistingPropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

or you can create a base class and put attribute `NotMapped` on your properties

Comment: I'll take your word for it that the interface property will work, but since you added the `MetadataType` attribute, I think that needs explaining.

Answer (score 4):

To ignore all classes of specific interface for EF Core I used this code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {

         var multitenantTypes = typeof(IMultiTenantEntity)
            .Assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(x => typeof(IMultiTenantEntity).IsAssignableFrom(x))
            .ToArray();

        foreach (var typeToIgnore in multitenantTypes)
        {
            builder.Ignore(typeToIgnore);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `NotMapped` attribute on such properties in the model class.

Or you can ignore the properties using reflection in DBContext class's `OnModelCreating` method like below.

```
foreach(var property in typeof(INotPersistingProperties).GetProperties())
    modelBuilder.Types().Configure(m => m.Ignore(property.Name));
```

Comment: That is the point, i can't fine the modelBuilder.Types() method, otherwise i could write  modelBuilder.Types<INotPersistingProperties>().Configure(c => c.Ignore(p=>p.MyNotPersistingPropertyA ));

Comment: which EF Core version you have?

Comment: I am not sure about it, but can you try modelBuilder.Entity<INotPersistingProperties>().Ignore(c => c.PropertyName);

Comment: I think so...im going to try

Comment: @GhiniAntonio you can try Ivan Stoev's solution, it will definitely work. You can trust his solutions anytime :)